# Creating a local memory copy of a global uint256

Tags: solidity, memory, memory-pointer

I'm struggling to find any documentation that describes how to create a local memory copy of a global uint256 variable. Consider the following example:

```
contract MyContract {
    uint256 myInt = 0;

     function setter(uint256 newValue) external {
         myInt = 5;
     }

     function getAndReset() external returns (uint256) {
         uint256 value = myInt; //This appears to be a reference
         myInt = 0;
         return value; //This always returns zero, even if setter() has been called
     }
}
```

In this case, the variable "value" in the getAndReset() function appears to be a reference to the global storage variable "myInt", and any changes to value results in myInt also being changed. How can I create a local memory copy of myInt so that the above code functions properly?

Comment: The contract works as expected `uint256 value = myInt` copies the value, it isn't a reference.

Answer (score 1):

The error in the code is that `value` is being assigned as a reference to `myInt`, resulting in `value` always reflecting the current state of `myInt`. To fix this, directly assign `myInt` to `value` to create a local copy.

Code Snippet:

```
function getAndReset() external returns (uint256) {
    uint256 value = myInt; // Create a local copy of myInt
    myInt = 0; // Reset myInt
    return value; // Return the local copy
}
```

Comment: I can see that I missed the returns type off the getAndReset() function signature, thanks for pointing that out - I've now fixed it. But beyond that I don't see a difference between your function body and mine.